# How to export data in CSV from Apex?

Tags: salesforce, visualforce, apex

I'm exporting data from Apex to CSV. Data is coming to CSV from JSONObject but its coming with all the Html tags. I don't want Html tags in CSV. Wanna to display data only. I have taken a jsonobject and reading data from json.

```
    // JsonData
    String myObj = { "name":"John", "age":30, "car":null };
    myObj = (List<JsnApx>) System.JSON.deserialize(myObj, List<JsnApx>.class);

    // code I have used to convert in CSV from Apex.
    public PageReference SaveAsCSV() {
        pb1=false;
        renderAsExcel='application/vnd.csv#Commission Summary Report.csv';
        return null;
        } 

    //vf page
    <apex:repeat value="{!myObj }" var="a" id="total" >
          <span styleClass="alldatatables" var="ca" cellpadding="5" rowClasses="alldatarows">
          <tr style="border:1px solid #000;">
               <td>{!a.name}</td>
               <td>{!a.age}</td>
               <td>{!a.car}</td>
          </tr></span>
    </apex:repeat>
```

Answer (score 0):

I might be going the obvious and simple route but what about the data exporter?

Answer (score 0):

You've included all kinds of HTML tags like `span`, `tr`, `td`, what did you expect? Excel will try to display a html table properly but that doesn't mean your file format is OK.

Try something like this (I've used similar in VF email template in plaintext section, should be OK on normal page too)

```
<apex:repeat value="{!records}" var="r">
{!r.Name},
<apex:outputText value="{0, date,yyyy-MM-dd},">
    <apex:param value="{!r.Date__c}" /> 
</apex:outputText>
<apex:outputText value="{!r.Account__r.Name}" />,
<apex:outputText value="{!r.Type__c}" />,
<apex:outputText value="{!r.Status__c}" />
</apex:repeat>
```

If you get newline issues maybe add `<br/>` at the end